# PYTHON: How to show print username and password?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json

x = ''' {
   "result":{
      "firstList":[
         {
            "username":"a@gmail.com",
            "password":"123"
         }
      ]
   },
   "size":1,
   "took":436
} ''' # The Json

seloco = json.loads(x)
print(seloco) # Print Json
```

How can I print username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Like that :

```
>>> print(seloco['result']['firstList'][0]['username'])
a@gmail.com
>>> print(seloco['result']['firstList'][0]['password'])
123
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

x = ''' {
   "result":{
      "firstList":[
         {
            "username":"a@gmail.com",
            "password":"123"
         }
      ]
   },
   "size":1,
   "took":436
} ''' # The Json

seloco = json.loads(x)
print(seloco) # Print Json
user = seloco["result"]["firstList"][0]
username = user["username"]
password = user["password"]
print(username)
print(password)
```